# Is there a way to prevent Prettier in VS Code from adding excessive lines when formatting HTML?

Tags: html, visual-studio-code, formatting

When I'm formatting code with Prettier on, it wraps the text which I do want to happen, but it creates more lines of code.

This is how I want it to be:

[image: Code]

But when I save with Prettier, it creates a lot of lines.

[image: Code with Prettier]

For legibility, is the first one better? Or I shouldn't be concern about it?

Is there a way to configure Prettier the way I want?

Comment: Prettier is not very configurable, on purpose: https://prettier.io/docs/en/option-philosophy.html
In my opinion, the point of code formatters is to not have to worry about making all these choices. Just let it do its thing and save your brainpower for the harder problems.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the Prettier docs:

- https://prettier.io/blog/2018/11/07/1.15.0.html#whitespace-sensitive-formatting
- https://prettier.io/docs/en/options.html#html-whitespace-sensitivity

> - `"css"` - Respect the default value of CSS display property. For Handlebars treated same as `strict`.
> - `"strict"` - Whitespace (or the lack of it) around all tags is considered significant.
> - `"ignore"` - Whitespace (or the lack of it) around all tags is considered insignificant.

I'd try using `strict` for the `--html-whitespace-sensitivity` option. If that doesn't work, try the other values.